# CONVERT_TZ for Epoch?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, epoch

I wasn't able to find a clear answer but is it possible to use MYSQL's CONVERT_TZ function on a Epoch INT ?

Reading here it sounds like it only works with actual datetime fields https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Anyone know otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

`convert_tz()` takes an argument of `datetime` datatype.

You can use `from_unixtime()` to turn the epoch value to a date first:

```
convert_tz(from_unixtime(myepoch), from_tz, to_tz)
```

If you want the result as an epoch value as well:

```
unix_timestamp(convert_tz(from_unixtime(myepoch), from_tz, to_tz))
```